# File content is different in Docker image vs mounted folder

Tags: spring-boot, docker, file, inputstream

I have a mounted folder and I download files into this folder through Spring boot application in docker container.

File content is correct in my macbook's mounted folder but it is different when I check the same file content within docker image.

```
FCS3.0         256    4336    4342 5459165       0       0
$BEGINANALYSIS^L0^L$ENDANALYSIS^.....
```

vs

```
FCS3.0         256    4336    4342 5459165       0       0
RFfr.E.=.D.H.CC@^@D.^Q.B.Q.DoQGD        ^E^_E^X.{^@^@^@^@G.!.G..^@G._^YGm^W.G^^@^@G...Ex^D.E.JRE.o^^C.^\)C
s3C.^Y.B..^@Dj..C...E%L^@^@^@^@^@G.^YZG..^@G.U.G%^\.G .^@G...D...F~%.E.B^TE...C.+.Eb.)B^D..Dk~^TC...C7..^@^@^@^@H6
D..
```

What can be the reason for this? Is there any settings that I am not aware of?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache python3 \
&& python3 -m ensurepip \
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools \
&& rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
rm -r /root/.cache

VOLUME ...
ADD ...
ADD ...
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ...
```

Comment: What is your docker image? This to me looks like an encoding issue

Comment: @SirHawrk what do you mean by 'what is your docker image'? Like how I create it?

Comment: I mean waht docker image do you use. What base Image and what additional things do you install. 

Maybe just post your dockerfile

Comment: @SirHawrk Thank you. I just added my dockerfile to the post.